# Spinner setIncrement issue in swt java

Tags: java, swt, spinner

I was trying out the swt spinner example from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/createandinitializeaSWTspinnerwidget.htm website.

Below is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;

public class Snippet184 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    spinner.setMinimum(0);
    spinner.setMaximum(10);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
    spinner.setIncrement(3);
    spinner.setPageIncrement(100);
    spinner.pack();
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Considering above code, the problem I am facing is that when I try to increment the spinner 4th time, the value of the spinner should stop at 9 (as increment=3, it should not increment beyond 9 here), but instead it goes on till 10(Max Value) and then stops.
Is there any solution to make it stop at 9?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything, the native control that SWT uses does the increment.

Comment: Yeah, the increment happens, but in above case the incremented value should stop at 9, but it always stops at max value which I don't want it to happen.

Comment: What I am saying is that there does not seem to be anything in the SWT Java code for Spinner that would let you change this. Actually doing the increment is not done by the Java code, rather it is done by the native control that SWT uses - different on each platform.

Comment: So you mean to say that it's the default behaviour of SWT spinner and there's nothing I can do to change this behaviour? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is the default behaviour of the native control that Spinner uses - which is different on each platform. So it might behave differently on macOS, Linux and Windows. I don't see a way to change it.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, Thank you